# jQuery UI accordion working in MVC 4 debug mode but not in the release

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, accordion

I work on an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

I updated jQuery, jQuery UI and all other nuget packages in my project. Built it and ran it to see that no problems occured. Everything worked so I continiued development for several days.

After a while I published the project to a test-server I have to see how it looked on Ipad, Iphone etc. And then I realized that the jQuery-UI accordion stopped working.

It renders, but does not respond on click. This goes for all browsers. I found this strange since the only difference is that the MVC bundeling i applied in release mode and as far as I understand it either minifies the jQuery file or chooses the minified version (the latter probably beeing what is does here since it is added when updating using nuget).

> The jQuery version is: 2.0.3
>
> The jQuery-ui version is: 1.10.3

In Chrome console the error reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined

OK, so i realize this might be the result of one of my jQuery assemblies references $.browser that apparently was removed in jQuery 1.9.

However the fact that it works in debug mode (using the non-minified versions) leads me to think that it might not be that. I could almost think that it is a problem with the minified versions, but that should not be possible either.

Anyone knows why this happens and know how to fix it?

**Update**
As requested I attach most of the code. The strange thing is that this works in debug mode, but not in release. I cannot see why there would be any significant changes that should cause this problem:

> _Layout.cshtml

[image: _Layout.cshtml]

> Bundleconfig.cs

[image: BundleConfig.cs]

> The view (which calls a partial view)

[image]

> The partial view

[image]

> The jquery code

[image]

> The javascript error in Chrome

[image]

> Bigger view of the error in chrome

[image]

Just to add. After posting this I removed the duplicate loading of modernizr (the telerik custom one was added without me noticing). The problem still persists.

**Update 2**
I turned off the optimizations in bundleconfig.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

This allowed me to see what was throwing an error in jquery-ui, and it seems indeed to be the $.browser that was removed. It seems that it actually loads two old versions of jquery (current + 1.6.4 and 1.7.1) together with the new one and two versions of jquery-ui (current + 1.8.16) the last one throwing an error. None of these files are loaded in my solution or in the file folder.

[image]
[image]

This seems to be a publish problem, but disguised by the bundling and minification... I'll try to fix this and see if it works.

Comment: Please post some codes for better understanding, as Microsoft have some different jQuery codes that might solve problem. thank you

Comment: It is hard without any code, etc. However, one important thing you may try is to add jQuery Migrate to your project. This will bring all deprecated functionality back and you will still be able to use jQuery >= 1.9 and have your accordion working.

Comment: @Tobias Yes I've read about that, but still I cannot understand the problem. At some point I probably have to solve this anyway. And it doesn't explain whyt this happens only in release mode. I can give you a link to the site itself, but would prefer not to post it here.

Comment: @cfs If you are not using jquery unobtrusive and validate then you may try to comment them for now. Another thing can you compare using any web dev tools in the browser what js files are actually included in debug and release to compare them. This would help because maybe you are missing sth. somwhere jquery related that is added and messes up so it works in debug but not in the release.

Comment: @Tobias I'm not loading jquery validation on this page and it is not loaded on the page. I have compared the files as you say, but I cannot find any difference other than the minified version is used where that is possible. Of cource this also leads to unreadable javascript. I could try to load the un-minfied scripts in the release - maybe easier to identify the problem.

Comment: @cfs You must not allow the situation like on the screenshot: you have 3 different versions of jQuery and 2 versions of jQuery UI. You use Kendo, check if it doesn't automatically add jQuery by itself. You should end up with ONE jQuery and ONE jQueryUI.

Comment: @Tobias Yeah, I know, but I had no idea that this was possible. I have litterly tried everything except finding a way to disable bundeling and "debug" on the test server which gave me an eureka moment. See my solution below and you will see I have been far off regarding my assumptions of where the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this was not at all a problem with the code itself, and I learned something new that might be of help to others.

Setting

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Was what helped me solve this.

Obviously the Asp.Net MVC 4 bundling bundles every script that is found in the folder where it is released, not what is in the solution folder in Visual Studio. I did not think of this at all... But in retrospect it kind of makes sense.

Combined with the fact that VS default publishing settings does not remove files that does not equal the files that you publish means that when removing i.e. an old version of Jquery and adding a new one, the old one still remains on the server.

Add the default bundling using {version} for jquery selection and you have one unreadable jquery file throwing error. Not until you disable bundling and minification it becomes obvious that I in this circumstance loaded 3 versions of Jquery:

> Before

[image]

> After

[image]

The solution? Easy, just have to expand a setting called "File publish options" in the publish wizard and check "Remove additional files...":

[image]

Thanks for the suggestions. It helped me look the right places, but I was not able to imagine this beeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add '"~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.all.css"'
Note: although you have called all modules separately sometimes calling single file makes difference. As we might miss some dependent file in choosing separate modules.

In BundleConfig.cs you need to add/modify like..

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.all.css"
));
```

if in your locals the file of jQueryUI exist that will do the trick for the same(that might be possible problem that makes it working on Local Testing).

Your _layout.cs will be like..

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

as you are not rendering jqueryUI that we need to call and render saperately after jQuery.

And your Section script should be called like this,

```
@section Scripts{
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")*@
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#accordian").accordian();
});
```

}

This is what I will suggest and should work, with MVC things are really small to identify exact problem, So I have provided all these lines, thank you,

Do post back if problem persist.

Comment: Thaks for the suggestion. Did some tests now but the problem is still there. It seems like the problem is that jquery ui is calling a property called safari on an object that doesn't have that property. It might be as you say that some files are accessible in debug mode, that makes calling the property "safari" possible, but not in release mode. Have no idea where and how this is possible. Don't feel this is css related, however nothing surprises me when it comes to this kind of stuff so I try the suggestions I get.

Comment: I can see that you are not able to post link! :( 
You are testing this on Safari, or some other browser? Please try testing on FireFox/ Chrome browser and reply. I think adding the above resourve should work, also see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ as you are working with Kendo; Adding `$.noConflict();` should make difference

Comment: I might have found the solution (re: my update above). No I tested this on safari, firefox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: NoConflict will surely help in this case also :)